# Make table in report undivideable between two print pages

Tags: split, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm currently creating a `.rdlc` report with several tables. Is there any way how to make a table do not split between two print pages.

I mean - when it is not possible to print the whole table on the first page, leave the space blank on the first page and than print the whole table on the second page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may work.make KeepTogether property =true  for the table

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just set the KeepTogether property to true.